# Use the definition to prove that $\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}=2^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

This is a question from Cambridge, Downing sample test

> Using the definition $\left( \begin{array}{c}
>  \text{n}\\
>  \text{k}\\
> \end{array} \right) =\frac{\text{n!}}{\text{k!}\left( \text{n}-\text{k} \right) !}
> $
>   , prove that $
> \sum_{\text{j}=0}^{\text{n}}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
>  \text{n}\\
>  \text{j}\\
> \end{array} \right) =2^{\text{n}}}
> $

Of course I know how to prove this by considering the subsets, or by binomial expansion.

But how to do it by definition? No idea about it.

Comment: Use  induction..

Comment: This is why I dont want to define "this symbol" this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "definition"? I think it is impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[x^m]f(x)$ stand for the coefficient of $x^m$ in the Maclaurin series of $f(x)$. We have:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\cdot\frac{1}{(n-k)!}=n!\cdot[x^n]\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^2=n!\cdot[x^n]e^{2x}=n!\cdot\frac{2^n}{n!}=2^n. $$